# Windows phone7 emulator requires constant refresh

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have the tools installed for windows phone 7 development.

But, when I run the any of the sample apps I have to manually refresh my emulator's app window to see any changes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or maybe a setting is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What version is your Driver Model? You have to have WDDM 1.1 as a minimum requirement. You can check your drive model by going to start..."dxdiag". Then click on the 'Display' tab and on the right hand side, there should be a label called "Driver Model".

Comment: Yes, driver model WDDM 1.1 is present.

Comment: what specificly do you mean by "refresh my emulator's app window"?

Comment: I have to minimize it and restore the emulator window

Comment: Are you using multiple monitors? I've had this a few times when the emulator is on a second monitor.

Comment: no, just on my laptop. A Bootcamp'd macbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it on every machine I've tried- but they all have various Nvidia cards (desktop and mobile).

When I posted about this on the wp7 forums, they talked about wdm 1.1 (which I've got) and so far I have no fix.

My machines are all 64bit, so I'm wondering if this isn't some issue with them or the nvidia drivers- but I don't experience any other problems with the drivers outside of the emulator.

I think we're stuck for a while anyway...